# The word "(Array)" is printing in my table instead of the actual objects array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

All the code is within the same index file and same class. I can't seem to figure out why its not calling. Both objects themselves work in a call 2-3 lines right above, outside this table.... I tried calling them inside the table to no avail.   They just pop up the word '(Array)' in both boxes. Is their a syntactical thing i am missing?   On my website I print the table, with the missing functions inside table, and the two tables that are supposed to be inside the table printed right above and below the table.   For reference, my website for the school project:     http://www.wallofkron.x10host.com

```
<?php

$companyobject = new BurgerJoint();      //object created


$companyobject->getLeftNavBar($companyobject->navbar_array);    //call to leftnav bar works


$companyobject->displayProduct($burgerarray);   // burger table also works outside of table



print "<TABLE style='width:100%'height=200 BORDER='1'>
<TR><TD style='width:15%'>$companyobject->getLeftNavBar($companyobject->navbar_array)
</TD>
<TD>$companyobject->displayProduct($burgerarray)
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>";



function displayProduct($array){
 print "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";

 foreach ($array as $oneitem) {
 print "<TR><TD>$oneitem</TD></TR>";
 } print "</TABLE>";
}




function getLeftNavBar($array){

print "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
print "<TR><TD><A HREF=$value>$key</A></TD></TR>";
}

print "</TABLE>";
}


?>
```

Comment: what is the result if you use: print_r($companyobject); ?

Comment: the result is a dump of the array.... check the website under the table to see the dump

Comment: can you edit with the function displayProduct in the question?

Comment: edit with the function?

Comment: in your question include the code of the functions you use

Comment: disregard that comment...... well, the function displayproduct() is in the class, seperate file, that index file imports and creates an object out of.

Comment: I added the two functions and the object creation at the top..... and the examples of the code that I called right above the table that im trying to create

Comment: take a look at my answer i think that might be the problem

Comment: I understood your answer. But it made the website all screwy.  Refresh if you want to see.   I am new to php but I have taken java, c++  and basic before so i understand the structure pretty well. I think......   Why wouldn't the calls to the objects work inside a table when they work 2-3 lines right above the table?

Comment: why not just make a default html template in it? then use the php variables to fill the template

Comment: With php, I am also somewhat new to HTML.... I did have a little experience with html back in the myspace days but it is limited.... Would you mind explaining what you mean.

Comment: you can just use html in a php file like you normally would use html, then you can just add anywhere on the page <?php php things here?> so for example you make the header then you just add the text using the php, the same for the rest

Comment: Im not sure I could do that. Plus im not sure it would help solve the problem at hand.

Comment: posted in my answer and example of how you could do it with html templating

Comment: OOOOO alright alright, Thats really helpful.  Thanks dude. Im gonna try to restructure it

Comment: please do notice that you actually still have to make the footer again:P i have made the code with your information from the question, if you would use it like how i showed then you wont need the object functions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

i think i noticed the problem:

```
<?php

print "<TABLE style='width:100%'height=200 BORDER='1'>
<TR><TD style='width:15%'>$companyobject->getLeftNavBar($companyobject->navbar_array)
</TD>
<TD>$companyobject->displayProduct($companyobject->burger_array)
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>";
```

?>

i think that the problem was that you were not reffering to the actual burgerarray inside the object companyobject.

as told in the comment it would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bob's Burgers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header style="background:orange; width:100%;">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <?php foreach($companyobject->navbar_array as $nav){
                     echo $nav
                }?>
        </header>
        <main style="width:100%;">
            <table style="height:200px; border:1px solid black;">
                <?php foreach($companyobject->burger_array as $burger):?>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $burger; ?></td></tr>
                <? endforeach; ?>
            </table>
         </main>
</html>
```

Comment: the two calls were made in different styles, one was passing a parameter with the object and the other was using the object....  It was the way the professor was trying to teach it.

Comment: Theres 3 classes in 3 seperate files.....  Index.php, Company.php and BurgerJoint.php...........  Burgerjoint inherits from and imports the file from  company..... Index, which is my main file, imports BurgerJoint and creates an object from it.

Comment: Also, If you check the website once more, I un-commented the code right above the table that shows that the same calls in the table work outside the table for both the objects I want to put inside the table

Comment: @WallofKron please do note that if you are using objects that the mostly used way of programming in oop is not to pass all the data but to make the information inside the class private and create functions that returns the correct value.